# How to select subseqent pairs from one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have a table which contains data from several sensors. Rows are added when special event occurs on sensor. Sensor has event sequence number which always growth and cannot be less than sequence number of previous event, but it's not guaranteed that it grows by constant value. It may be sequence of `1, 2, 5,6, 11,...`. Each row contains sensor ID, event sequence number, timestamp when event occurred and some data. I want to get pairs of subsequent event for each sensor sorted by timestamp.

Example of table structure with some dummy data:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  sensor_id  INT,
  event_seq INT,
  ts        INT,
  data      TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT event_pk PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id, event_seq)
);

INSERT INTO event (sensor_id, event_seq, ts, data) VALUES
  (1, 1, 1, '1st sensor 1st event'),
  (1, 2, 2, '1st sensor 2nd event'),
  (2, 1, 2, '2nd sensor 1st event'),
  (2, 2, 3, '2nd sensor 2nd event'),
  (1, 3, 3, '1st sensor 3rd event'),
  (1, 4, 4, '1st sensor 4th event'),
  (2, 3, 5, '2nd sensor 3rd event'),
  (1, 5, 5, '1st sensor 5th event'),
  (2, 4, 6, '2nd sensor 4th event'),
  (2, 5, 7, '2nd sensor 5th event'),
  (1, 6, 7, '1st sensor 6th event');
```

Currently, I use SQLite DB. I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT
  a.data,
  a.ts,
  b.data,
  b.ts
FROM event AS a
  JOIN event AS b ON a.sensor_id = b.sensor_id AND a.event_seq < b.event_seq
GROUP BY a.sensor_id, a.event_seq
HAVING min(b.event_seq)
ORDER BY a.ts, b.ts
```

And it actually provides result that I need ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7c6910/1)):

```
|                 data | ts |                 data | ts |
|----------------------|----|----------------------|----|
| 1st sensor 1st event |  1 | 1st sensor 2nd event |  2 |
| 1st sensor 2nd event |  2 | 1st sensor 3rd event |  3 |
| 2nd sensor 1st event |  2 | 2nd sensor 2nd event |  3 |
| 1st sensor 3rd event |  3 | 1st sensor 4th event |  4 |
| 2nd sensor 2nd event |  3 | 2nd sensor 3rd event |  5 |
| 1st sensor 4th event |  4 | 1st sensor 5th event |  5 |
| 2nd sensor 3rd event |  5 | 2nd sensor 4th event |  6 |
| 1st sensor 5th event |  5 | 1st sensor 6th event |  7 |
| 2nd sensor 4th event |  6 | 2nd sensor 5th event |  7 |
```

But I'm using `min` function in `HAVING` without any expression that returns boolean. It works but according to documentation it should be boolean expression, so I don't know if I'm missing something or this is bug or whatever.
More over, it's is possible, that I need  to switch to PostgreSQL at one day, and this query actually errors on Postgres `argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type integer Position: 177`

So my question is how to write this query so it works on both SQLite and Postgres.
Additionally, any suggestions of indexes to speedup the query?

Answer (score 0):

(My first comment on Stackoverflow, be gentle :-)

The below query is a different way of achieving the same. I'm not sure (at all) if it's any faster. On PostgreSQL you will certainly resort to window function LEAD or LAG, which should perform better.

```
SELECT
  a.data,
  a.ts,
  b2.data,
  b2.ts
FROM event AS a
  JOIN (select b.sensor_id, b.data, b.ts 
    from event AS b 
    where a.sensor_id = b.sensor_id
    AND a.event_seq < b.event_seq
    order by event_seq DESC
    limit 1 ) b2
on b2.sensor_id = a.sensor_id
```

Comment: Does not work for me. `Error: no such column: a.sensor_id`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `JOIN` with equality conditions:

```
SELECT a.data, a.ts, b.data, b.ts
FROM event a JOIN
     event b
     ON a.sensor_id = b.sensor_id AND a.event_seq = b.event_seq - 1
ORDER BY a.ts, b.ts;
```

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, it's not guaranteed that sequence number is increased by constant value. I updated my question.